# ForEach in Javascript skipping entries?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking an array of text entries to see if they fit ZIP code format. Here's my code:

```
var invZIPs;

ZIP.forEach(function(z, i) {
    console.log(z);
    console.log(ZIP);
    if(!isZIP(z)){
        invZIPs += "(" + z + ")";
        ZIP.splice(i,1);
    }
    console.log(ZIP);
});

if(invZIPs != ""){
    console.log(""Ignored unrecognized entries: " + invZIPs");
}
```

For debugging, I'm printing the forEach entry and the array before and after the check. This is my output.

```
1
["1", "2", "31833", "4", "5"]
["2", "31833", "4", "5"]
31833
["2", "31833", "4", "5"]
["2", "31833", "4", "5"]
4
["2", "31833", "4", "5"]
["2", "31833", "5"]
```

Why is it not checking some entries?

Comment: You're iterating over a collection that you modify inside the loop. What could go wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it not checking some entries?

The range of elements that will be visited is determined **before** the callback loop starts, and continues with the next one even if you remove the entry you're visiting. (See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach).) So if you modify the array during iteration, you're going to get strange effects. For instance, say entry `0` is not valid; you remove it, making entry `1` entry `0`, entry `2` entry `1`, etc.; then the loop continues with entry `1` and the (new) entry `0` is never checked.

`Array#filter` is probably the better choice in that situation.

```
ZIP = ZIP.filter(function(z, i) {   // Note we're assigning the new array
    console.log(z);
    console.log(ZIP);
    if(!isZIP(z)){
        invZIPs += "(" + z + ")";
        return false;               // Leave it out of the result
    }
    console.log(ZIP);
    return true;                    // Include it in the result
});
```

---

Side note: You also never give `invZIPs` an initial value. From your use of `+=`, you probably want

```
var invZIPs = "";
```

Comment: Also it makes sense to take out anything free variable mutations as well, `invZIPs`. Which leads to `ZIP = ZIP.filter(isZIP);` (this message is more to the OP, not to the T.J. Crowder)

Comment: @zerkms: Well, they're using `invZIPs` for something later... :-)

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Obviously the index would still increment after I delete something. Filter works much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, the fist time through the loop the member at index 0 is tested and spliced from the array, so all the members are shuffled down one.

On the next iteration, the member at index 1 is tested. Since the previous loop did a splice and moved everything down, the member at index 1 is the one that was at index 2 originally, and so on. So every time a member is spliced, the next member is skipped.

The solution is to iterate from the end, not the start, so splicing doesn't cause this affect.